# Problem with freeing memory in c++ code due to invalid pointer

Tags: c++, free

I have simple code that calculates PSNR. I have two type of images, with signed and unsigned data, so I have to cover both cases in my code. Now, when I run code, I get printed right PSNR value, however I get the following error:

munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Aborted (core dumped)

I know it has something with pointers. I would appreciate if someone can point me to the problem, so I can explore further in more details. And also, what would be the best solution in this particular case? The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "string.h"
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, w, h, t, b; 
    double mse, d, psnr;
    bool isSigned;
    FILE    *in_file1, *in_file2;

    int *image5;
    int *image6;
    unsigned int *image7;
    unsigned int *image8;

    if(argc!=7){
        printf("Usage: %s file1 file2 width height bit_resolution is_signed\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    in_file1=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    in_file2=fopen(argv[2],"rb");
    w=atoi(argv[3]);
    h=atoi(argv[4]);
    b=atoi(argv[5]);
    isSigned = !strcmp(argv[6], "true");
    t=w*h;


    if (isSigned){
        image5=(int *)calloc(t, sizeof(int));
        image6=(int *)calloc(t, sizeof(int));

        fread(image5,sizeof(int),w*h,in_file1);
        fread(image6,sizeof(int),w*h,in_file2);
    }
    else{

        image7=(unsigned int *)calloc(t, sizeof(unsigned int));
        image8=(unsigned int *)calloc(t, sizeof(unsigned int));

        fread(image7,sizeof(unsigned int),w*h,in_file1);
        fread(image8,sizeof(unsigned int),w*h,in_file2);
    }


    mse=0.;
    if(isSigned)
    {
        for(i=0;i<t;i++){
            d=(double)image5[i]-(double)image6[i]; 
            mse+=d*d;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<t;i++){
            d=(double)image7[i]-(double)image8[i]; 
            mse+=d*d;
        }
    }
    mse=mse/t;

    d=1.;
    for(i=0;i<b;i++) d*=2;
    d-=1.;

    psnr=20*log10(d)-10*log10(mse);

    printf("P=%f MSE=%f PSNR=%fdB\n",d, mse, psnr);

    free(image5);
    free(image6);
    free(image7);
    free(image8);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is that the above is not C++ code. It is C code that uses error-prone memory allocation design patterns that are the only option in C. I'm sure that there's a bug somewhere in there, that results in memory corruption. But the easiest fix is to simply scrap the whole thing and rewrite it from scratch in proper, modern, safe C++ using containers to manage memory allocation correctly, and employing container and iterators in a manner that can be logically proven to be correct and nto access invalid memory locations.

Comment: 1. Why are you using `calloc` and `free` in C++? 2. Why are you leaving the pointers uninitialized? Your `if` and `else` will only initialize one of the 2 pairs of pointers, leaving the other *indeterminate*  3. Why are you manually managing your memory at all? C++ provides containers in the standard library that will take care of it for you (see e.g.: `std::vector`)

Comment: why are you using pointers everywhere? why `calloc` ? Why not `fstream` and no `std::vector`? Your code looks like "C with unused C++ includes".

Comment: You are freeing unallocated memory, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you free all inconditionaly :

```
free(image5);
free(image6);
free(image7);
free(image8);
```

but

```
if (isSigned){
    image5=(int *)calloc(t, sizeof(int));
    image6=(int *)calloc(t, sizeof(int));
    ...
}
else{
    image7=(unsigned int *)calloc(t, sizeof(unsigned int));
    image8=(unsigned int *)calloc(t, sizeof(unsigned int));
     ...
}
```

if *isSigned* then *image7* and *image8* are not initialized, else *image5* and *image6* are not initialized, the behavior is undefined

initialize all theses pointer to NULL or if *isSigned* just free *image5* and *image6* else only *image7* and *image8*

---

Are you sure the tag C++ must not be C ?

---

Doing

> ```
> w=atoi(argv[3]);
> h=atoi(argv[4]);
> b=atoi(argv[5]);
> ```

is unsure, if the argument are not valid number `atoi` silently returns 0, I recommand you to never use `atoi` but `strtol` or `scanf` checking their result

You also access to `argv` without checking first `argc`, if not enough arguments are given the behavior is undefined

you also do not check you was able to open the files, and you do not check `fread` result

Comment: Yes, C is correct. However you pointed to the right problem. It's easy to fix now, when I see the problem. Thank you. atoi should be fine since Im the only one that is using this code. Not part of bigger project. But thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @MilosR. even if for you I recommend to not use it, that will allow you to get the right reflexes in the other cases.